# Languages that are not subset, but are union

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, proof-techniques

Are there examples of regular languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, where $L_1$ and $L_2$ is not a subset of each other but  that $(L_1 \cup L_2)^* = L_1^* \cup L_2^*$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $L_1=\{a\}, L_2=\{\epsilon\}$. Obviously both languages are regular and neither is a subset of the other. We then have 
$$
(L_1\cup L_2)^*=(a+\epsilon)^*=a^*
$$ 
and since 
$$
L_1^*=a^*,\quad L_2^*=\epsilon^*=\epsilon 
$$
we have
$$
L_1^*\cup L_2^*=a^*\cup \epsilon = a^*
$$

Comment: More generally, any two regular languages where $L_2 \subseteq L_1^*$ and which aren't subsets of each other will do.